# How can I do to justify a paragraph with Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, justify

Good day.

I'm using Apache POI 3.15 in order to create a Microsoft Word document in Java.
I cannot found a way to justify a text in a paragrapth.
In a XWPFParagraph there is only BOTH value (of ParagraphAlignment class), but really it adjust a text on left and right adding spaces from the words and if there are a few of them, the result is wrong.
How can I do to make it?

Best regards.

Stefano Errani

Answer (score 5):

```
        XWPFParagraph p1 = doc.createParagraph();
        p1.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.BOTH);
```

Comment: Good job pablo job. I find this useful for me too. Up for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
XWPFParagraph p1 = doc.createParagraph();
p1.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.BOTH);
```

It will justify all lines of paragraph, but if you add run.addBreak(); after run.addText(""); last line will have indentation of both.